# How to write responsive text for different screen sizes

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

If I want to make responsive text I would probably write something like that:

```
$(window).resize(function ()
{
      if $(document).width() <= 320) {
      $('#mydiv').html('something')
      }
      if $((document).width() > 320) && (document).width() <= 480)) {
      $('#mydiv').html('something longer')
      }    
      if $((document).width() > 480) && (document).width() <= 768)) {    

      }   
      //and so on     
}
```

I don't think it is most efficient (and messy code) - I think that there must be a way to make it easier - Let's assume that I can write this object which stores all the data:

```
    var divTextPerScreenWidthMap = {
       {'360','click'},
       {'480','click it'},
       {'768','click it right'},
       {'1024','you know you want to click it'},
       {'1280','click this button which is very long will help you'}
    }
```

After I have done so, is there a simple function I can write that takes this data and simplify my many-conditions function? some sort of way to tell javascript how to build me the specific function I need?

something like this thing but in real code:

```
for (objects in divTextPerScreenWidthMap) {
    create If Statement for Nth Object(object)
}
```

thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 2):

I think using a lookup table like that is a bit overkill. Note that your code becomes much simpler if you use `else if`s properly.

```
if $(document).width() <= 320) {
    $('#mydiv').html('something')
} else if ($(document).width() <= 480) {
    $('#mydiv').html('something longer')
} else if ($(document).width() <= 768) {    
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is a good way to shorten the code that I didn't think of - but I was looking for something that will be able to take objects - so I would have multiple objects that each one will be able to produce different results

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work - it'll set it once for the first screen width (360) then for each subsequent one, if the width is smaller than the document's width, it'll overwrite it.

```
var docWidth = $(document).width();
for (var i in divTextPerScreenWidthMap)
{
    if (parseInt(divTextPerScreenWidthMap[i][0]) < docWidth || i == 0)
    {
        // Set something here
        console.log( divTextPerScreenWidthMap[i][1] );
    }
}
```